# Mobile Push Contact Key Resolve

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilestudio

We have Salescloud and Marketing Cloud. Through MC connector we receive Salesforce 16-digit ID which is being used for Email sends from MC. We have recently configured Mobile Push APP in MC and tested the initial functionality of receiving push notifications.  I would like to use the same subscriber key which I have in All contacts of MC for email sends and also Mobile Push as well so that no duplicate contacts exist in MC.
Currently, we are receiving alphanumeric Values as the contact key in Mobile Push. I would like to know how I can make the above requirement possible

Comment: Two steps : 1 - setDelayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet(true), 2 - setContactKey(18-digitsID) described below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to deactivate the auto-registration, by calling `setDelayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet(true)` during the app init phase. This will ensure a random ContactKey is not pushed to MC. If you don't you [will have dups](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/381911/changing-the-contact-key-from-mobile-push-sdk-is-another-contact-actually-crea).

Of course you won't be able to send notifications until an actual key is sent to MC. In your use case you want to call `setContactKey` from the app with the 18-digits Lead or Contact ID.

You may ask the user in your app onboarding to input an identifying information (a custom userId of yours or an email) which will enable you to send the 18-digitsID back to the app, to finally call setContactKey.

Comment: Thanks Francois for responding. If I understand correctly this is the process.
Step 1 : User installs the App and Registers using the email address.
Step 2: Delay the registration by using a function that will ensure no random Alpha numeric contact key is created.
Step 3: From SDK, the App dev team needs to do an API call to CRM and get the associated SF ID for that email address.
Step 4: Now they have the SF ID and that needs to need to sent back to Marketing Cloud.

are these the right steps?

Comment: @rohan : Correct  If this solves your initial issue, please ✔️ accept the answer. Otherwise, feel free to ask for details.